# Does StringBuilder use more memory than String concatenation?

Tags: c#, string

I know the obvious performance advantage to using the StringBuilder is in C#, but what is the memory difference like?

Does the StringBuilder use more memory? and as a side note, what essentially does the stringbuilder do differently that makes it so much faster?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: `StringBuilder` is appropriate in cases where you are concatenating an arbitrary number of strings, which you don't know at compile time.

If you *do* know what strings you're combining at compile time, `StringBuilder` is basically pointless as you don't need its dynamic resizing capabilities.

Example 1: You want to combine "cat", "dog", and "mouse". This is exactly 11 characters. You could simply allocate a `char[]` array of length 11 and fill it with the characters from these strings. This is essentially what `string.Concat` does.

Example 2: You want to join an unspecified number of user-supplied strings into a single string. Since the amount of data to concatenate is unknown in advance, using a `StringBuilder` is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 16):

StringBuilder is not necessarily faster. As I recall, if you're concatentating fewer than a dozen strings, string concatentation (eiether via String.Concat or simple str1 + str2) is actually faster. The reason is that allocation and initialization of StringBuilder actually takes time.

The reason that StringBuilder is faster is that it creates an internal buffer that it adds strings to. If you are concatenating 20 strings, StringBuilder simply appends one after another to its buffer and finally returns the result when requested - via its ToString() method. (I'm assuming there is sufficient buffer space. Otherwise StringBuilder worries about re-allocating the buffer and has heuristics for helping it not re-allocate too many times.) If you were concatentating strings, each string concat would allocate a new string of length (str1.Length + str2.Length) and copy the first and second string into place. This results in a lot of re-copying of strings.

```
var result = str1 + str2 + str3 + ... + strN;
```

This will require N-1 allocations and N-1 copy operations. This can get very expensive for large N. Plus note that you're copying the contents of str1 N-1 times. Once to get the result of str1+str2. Then again to get the result of (str1+str2)+str3. With StringBuilder, each string is copied into the internal buffer only once, assuming the buffer is sufficiently large to hold the individual strings.

Comment: I believe the first few sentences of your closing paragraph are incorrect. A single line concatenating many strings in this way will, unless I'm mistaken, compile to a single `string.Concat` call, which allocates exactly enough space for the resulting string one time, without needing to perform multiple reallocations as you suggest.

Comment: The C# compiler might have that optimization. I haven't checked. More often than not, these types of concatentations are done inside a for loop, which cannot be optimized out. The C# compiler does optimize for the case where you're concatentating a series of const strings, which results in the compiler emitting a single const string and avoiding the run-time concatentation completely.

Answer (score 5):

I think you really should read this: [The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html), your answer of StringBuilder v/s Concat , after the jump