# accessing selected checkboxes in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview in which i am using checkbox in each row. i am trying to access checkbox of each row and trying to find out which checkboxes have been checked.buut when i try to run the below code.the condition always stands to be false and the inner if condition is never reached by the code.kindly help me.thanks in advance.

```
protected void btn_3id_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";
    string srr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
    {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
       if (chk.Checked==true)     
       {         
           if (str == "")    
           {
              str = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
           }     
           else     
           {         
              srr = str + "," + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();  
           } 
        }
    }
    Session["Card_id"] = str;
    Response.Redirect("ID.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine.
The problem could be you are binding the gridview at page load.
Try grid binding in the following section of page load

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //code to bind the gridview

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that you are binding your `gridview` on each page load without checking PostBack. That is causing the checkbox to loose its current state. So where you are assigning the DataSource to the Gridview , Check for PostBack like:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   GridView1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

also you can do some minor improvements in your code like your check:

```
if(chk.Checked == true)
```

can be replaced as:

```
if(chk.Checked) //Since it returns a bool value.
```

You can omit multiple string variables for concatenation. Its better if you use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), *(See [why it is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191079/stringbuilder-vs-string-concat))* so your code would be:

```
protected void btn_3id_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
    {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
       if (chk.Checked==true)     
       {         
              sb.Append() GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
       }     
    }
    Session["Card_id"] = sb.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("ID.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //
}
```

Postback plays important role in cs file. If you are clearing values on page load , you will null values of checkbox.
You code is fine.
Just try to do this...