# string value empty for each checkbox checked in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have this code where on the click of a button i want to get the Empid of all those checkboxes that are checked in each row. but the string variable str is always empty and doesnt take any value.why is this so? kindly help

```
   protected void btn_3id_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "";
        string srr = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                if (str == "")
                {
                    str = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    srr = str + "," + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        Session["card_id"] = str;
        Response.Redirect("ID.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15515279/961113

Comment: i only asked that question also...string str is always empty

Comment: Put a break point and see what you get in `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]`, also in the else part you are getting value from `Cell[1]`, is that the problem ?

Comment: Share your gridview code(.aspx part)

Comment: i am getting str = "" i.e. empty value...even if the checkbox is checked then also the code goes in if(str="") again and again.

Comment: my code doesnt reach the else part.that is a problem

Comment: @sharique in my gridview ID is the first column.

Comment: if your control name is Label then use str = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("yourlabelid")).Text; in place of str = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your control name is Label then use

```
str = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("yourlabelid")).Text;
```

in place of

```
str = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
```