# WPF continouous Text

Tags: c#, wpf

Which element is good, if I get continouous text from my COM and I want display it in a Box,like textBox.

I want keep the old text but add in a new line like:

```
COM Data1: 0xFF 14:10 PM
COM Data1: 0xA3 14:10 PM
COM Data1: 0x12 14:11 PM
....
```

If I use a textbox and do this

```
txtbox.Text = comData;
```

it replace my older text.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
txtbox.Text = txtBox.Text + Environment.NewLine + comData;
```

You can use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) as well for string concatenation like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void yourMethod()
{
  sb.Append(comData);
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
  txtBox.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

*(Why use StringBuilder See: [Stringbuilder vs String.Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191079/stringbuilder-vs-string-concat))*

Answer (score 3):

use a `listbox` or a `listview`,

add element one by one.

So for example in a loop you can do

```
for each item in ComData.item

listbox1.add = item

loop
```

and that would add a line below the last.